# Are rust-style const generics in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, generics

In TypeScript, literals are types. Const-generics would allow me to use the value of the literal inside the type it is a part of, e.g.

```js
class ImpreciseMoney<const MUL: number> {
    value: Number;

    constructor(value: number) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    normalize(): number {
        return this.value / MUL;
    }

    add<const RHS_MUL: number>(rhs: ImpreciseMoney<RHS_MUL>): ImpreciseMoney<MUL> {
        return new ImpreciseMoney<MUL>(this.normalize() + rhs.normalize());
    }
}

const JPY = 131.12;
const USD = 1;

let a = new ImpreciseMoney<JPY>(1000);
let b = new ImpreciseMoney<USD>(50);
let ab = a.add(b); // ImpreciseMoney<JPY> { value: 7555.75, };
```

Is this sort of thing possible in TypeScript?

Since this has been flagged for closure for not being specific, I guess I'll just describe what a const-generic is:

- literals can be passed as type arguments
- literals are also values
- can I use that value as a constant within an item that takes generic parameters (which could be literals?

Comment: Types have no runtime impact

Comment: @DanielA.White What is the relevance of this to my question?

Comment: `MUL` is a type and those can never be used at runtime. So `this.value / MUL` is not possible. That's what Daniel meant.

Comment: The code in your question can be rewritten in a way that the currency is passed as an argument and stored in a generic attribute like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Woke9W). Would this answer your question (in addition to the fact that types can't be used at runtime)?

Comment: @TobiasS. Yes, that would be a great answer! If you believe it is the closest approximation available in TypeScript. It looks like it achieves basically the same thing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During compilation, the TypeScript compiler strips away all typings and only emits the left-over JavaScript. This means that types can not be used to do anything at runtime.

*Literal types* are no exception to this rule. They may look like something the compiler could easily emit to the resulting JavaScript, but it would not align with the [Design Goals](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals) of the language.

([*enums*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) can be seen as an exception of this rule since they are types *with* runtime representations)

---

Most of the times you can use appropriate runtime representations which hold the values of the type you want to use.

We can rewrite `ImpreciseMoney`, so that it takes a value of the generic type `MUL` as a parameter in the constructor. This runtime value can then be set to a property `mul`.

```
class ImpreciseMoney<MUL extends number> {
    value: number;
    mul: MUL

    constructor(mul: MUL, value: number) {
        this.value = value;
        this.mul = mul
    }

    normalize(): number {
        return this.value / this.mul;
    }

    add(rhs: ImpreciseMoney<number>): ImpreciseMoney<MUL> {
        return new ImpreciseMoney(this.mul, this.normalize() + rhs.normalize());
    }
}
```

This pretty much achieves your goals. You have the property `mul` which can be used at runtime for computations but also the generic type `MUL` which holds the literal type of whatever was set to `mul`.

The only difference for the caller is that the type argument was replaced with another non-type argument.

```
const JPY = 131.12;
const USD = 1;

let a = new ImpreciseMoney(JPY, 1000);
let b = new ImpreciseMoney(USD, 50);
let ab = a.add(b);
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECSC2AHATgU2ASwqgsgewDtUBPAHhwFUAZaVADwBdUCATGAgV3gCNVkA+aAG8AsAChok6ADcwIDqgBc0Tjz4BucVOjwOIZZSritU4IQgNkHYAzzIAFLv3RDAGhlyFy1b2QBKYRNtSQYACywAOll5VGgAXg8YzQlgkPCICKd4nT0g6ABfYxTJAjt4OQwAL1R7P28uX0Di4LQGDmQCaDDI6IVoAHou9My9ZO1CsTywFhZ7ZFCIZQQUdCxcQhJSHz5+OrgkNExsfCIyQ0FRZu1W9s6iAHd9laP10-tujKd3D4jS5HKQFUagEANTQeYZP4AoG1PxjKQTCbiMwECzQABSAAUAJrZACMAGY8RE8QAmZIotEUADKABF8clxCBUAxoGBsg8noc1icSPYsdj3HiAAyiuFMlnQbgc1CPZbc44bYj2Gm09wAVmF4rEzNZYGlCTAEWms24cKAA)

Comment: Being the lazy programmers we are, we could use shorthand to define and assign the fields in the constructor: `constructor(public mul: MUL, public value: number) {}`.